# How to use here document or assign multiline string to variable in csh?

Tags: csh, here-document

I want to assign to variable to a multi-line string that contains a variable and then echo it. I attempted using here-doc as shown below. What is the best way to achieve this in csh?

```
set my_name="JOHN"
set my_var=<<EOF
"name":"${my_name}"
EOF

echo ${my_name}
echo ${my_var}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following ?

```
set my_var = '\
"name":"${my_name}" \
'
```

then:

```
echo $my_var:q
```